# How to config Django using pymysql as driver?

Tags: python, mysql, django, pymysql

I'm new to Django. It wasted me whole afternoon to config the MySQL engine. I am very confused about the database engine and the database driver. Is the **engine** also the **driver**?  All the tutorial said that the ENGINE should be 'django.db.backends.mysql', but how the ENGINE decide which driver is used to connect MySQL?

Every time it says 'django.db.backends.mysql', sadly I can't install MySQLDb and mysqlclient, but PyMysql and the official *mysql connector 2.1.3* has been installed. How could I set the driver to PyMysql or mysql connector?

Many thanks!

- OS: OS X Al Capitan
- Python: 3.5
- Django: 1.9

This question is not yet solved:
Is the **ENGINE** also the **DRIVER**?

Answer (score 75):

[You can import `pymsql` so it presents as MySQLdb](https://web.archive.org/web/20160516011717/http://www.codes9.com/programing-language/python/python3-5-django1-8-5-the-solution-of-the-import-pymysql-pymysql-install_as_mysqldb-installation-2). You'll need to do this *before* any django code is run, so put this in your `manage.py` file

```
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

Comment: And for the DATABASE entry: [`'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',`](http://www.marinamele.com/taskbuster-django-tutorial/install-and-configure-mysql-for-django)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no they are not the same.

The **engine**, in a Django context, is in reference to RDBMS technology. The **driver** is the library developed to facilitate communication to that actual technology when up and running. Letting Django know what engine to use tells it how to translate the ORM functions from a backend perspective. The developer doesn't see a change in ORM code but Django will know how to convert those actions to a language the technology understands. The driver then takes those actions (e.g. selects, updates, deletes) and sends them over to a running instance to facilitate the action.