# install MySQL-client for django in widows 10

Tags: python, django

i started a django project on my windows machine and i changed the db to my sql like below :

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'django',
    'USER': 'root',
    'PASSWORD': '',
    'HOST': 'localhost' 
}
}
```

now when i wanna migrate tables it gives this error :

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: mysqlclient 1.3.13 or newer is required; you have 0.9.3.
```

but when i run pip with version it says that this version is not available like below :

```
pip install pymysql==1.3.14
```

and it returns this error :

```
     ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pymysql==1.3.14 (from versions: 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.6.1, 0.6.2, 0.6.3, 0.6.4.dev1, 0.6.4, 0.6.6, 0.6.7, 0.7.0, 0.7.1, 0.7.2, 0.7.
3, 0.7.4, 0.7.5, 0.7.6, 0.7.7, 0.7.8, 0.7.9, 0.7.10, 0.7.11, 0.8.0, 0.8.1, 0.9.0, 0.9.1, 0.9.2, 0.9.3)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pymysql==1.3.14
```

any idea what should i do ??

Comment: `pymysql` is a different package entirely from `mysqlclient` - hence why that version doesn't exist.

Comment: which one i should install then ??

Comment: They are two different libraries - you choose. Instructions for using pymysql can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34777755/how-to-config-django-using-pymysql-as-driver