# Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h'

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am new to Python and Django. Now I would like to connect to mysql from Django and I just run `pip install mysqlclient`.

First I installed `xampp` and I just use `phpmyadmin` to connect MySQL and I created new database and tables

Second I installed Microsoft Builds Tools 2017

But this error is still showing.

So I just download the MySql and I got a zip file. I extracted and `mysql.h` exist in this folder. I don't know what I have to with this zip file. :(

Third I download the `mysql-installer.msi` and I installed MySQL and python connection.

but this error still happens.

I am really messing with this database.

So how can I connect to MySql from Django like other people does (They does like this is very easy.).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Python with embedded C source are always tricky to install under Windows. So, either you find a suitable binary (pre-compiled) wheel package for `mysqlclient`, or you try this instead.

https://pypi.org/project/PyMySQL/

PyMySQL is a pure Python implementation, so does not require the source code of the C client lib.

Ah! Read this too...

[How to config Django using pymysql as driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34777755/how-to-config-django-using-pymysql-as-driver)